# Typescript: how do you create a Copy of a type but change the property typeings

Tags: typescript, types

I want to create 2 types for an object. A type for the object itself and a type for the validation errors. These two types will have the same property names but the properties will have different typings.

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  married: boolean
}

type PersonValidationError = {
  name?: string,
  age?: string,
  married?: string
}
```

After a user fills out a form constructing a `Person` object I want to then run it through some validation and if there are errors I want to create the error object which will have error messages in the respective property. Is there a way I can tie the `PersonValidationError` to the `Person` type itself so that when i add more properties to `Person` I dont need to worry about them getting out of sync.

My first thought was to use `keyof`

```
type PersonValidationError = {
  [prop: keyof Person]: string
}
```

But this is not valid and `keyof` cant be used in a index signature to my understanding.

Also I know the `PersonValidationError` has all its properties marked as optional but its fine if I cant change the requirement of the props because I could always wrap it in a `Partial<>`

Comment: There's an awesome answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69277054/1205871 that will help some people

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types); it looks similar to an index signature but it uses the `in` keyword:

```
type PersonValidationError = { [K in keyof Person]?: string }
```

The `?` makes the properties optional.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAGnyiIYsIFcSAjBFgRJF4dCABNKvZMgA2EIqlwBfXLlCRYCFKgBqRWbXFFgtNAFFRyeJhxQA2gGko9KAGsIIZADMtSNAC6APyU1HSMUKpQQA)