# TypeScript copy existing interface but change type on one property

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```
interface IInternalListener {
  element: HTMLElement,
  id: string,
  type: string,
  listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject,
  useCapture: boolean
}
```

And I also want to use this interface:

```
interface IListener {
  element: HTMLElement,
  id: string | number,
  type: string,
  listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject,
  useCapture: boolean
}
```

The only difference being the type for `id`. I want to employ DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

How can I create this without copy paste. A [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) seems the way to go but in this answer here they are mapping all the props - [Typescript: how do you create a Copy of a type but change the property typeings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62143738/typescript-how-do-you-create-a-copy-of-a-type-but-change-the-property-typeings)

I only want to change one prop. How can I do this? I don't have to use mapped types, any viable solution is fair game.

Comment: Why not use a generic type with a type parameter representing the type of `id`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

### Way 1

Extract the common logic into a third interface the other two extend:

```js
interface IWhatever {
  element: HTMLElement,
  type: string,
  listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject,
  useCapture: boolean
}

interface IListener extends IWhatever {
  id: string
}

interface IInternalListener extends IWhatever {
  id: string | number
}
```

### Way 2

As Robby Cornelissen points out in the comments, you can use a generic:

```js
interface IListener<T> {
  id: T
  element: HTMLElement,
  type: string,
  listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject,
  useCapture: boolean
}
```

### Way 3

Lets say you don't own the IListener interface and can't change it but you want to reuse a lot of it for your other interface:

```js
interface IInternalListener extends Omit<IListener, 'id'> {
  id: string | number
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use extends and `Omit` utility type together.

Example

```js
interface IInternalListener {
  element: HTMLElement,
  id: string,
  type: string,
  listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject,
  useCapture: boolean
}

interface IListener extends Omit<IInternalListener, 'id'> {
    id: string | number
}
```

Basically, we will remove the `id` property and add it back with the preferred type you need.